# How can I visualize my React Component-Tree using a diagramming software?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm a visual learner, This would help me a lot in designing, implementing, testing etc.
I need a kinda **diagram** that visualizes props, state, events, input, processing, output etc for each component in the tree and **also** as a whole. I want to visualize the components themselves **and** the relationship between these components, using a software like omnigraffle or anything else.

Answer (score 16):

This can be achieved with a Browser Extension or a global npm package. (rarely a local one) Let me show you the two most popular tools.

**React Sight (chrome extension)**

React Sight is a live view of the component hierarchy tree of your React application with support for React Router and Redux.

Source: https://github.com/React-Sight/React-Sight

**React Monocle (npm package)**

React Monocle parses through your React source files to generate a visual tree graph representing your React component hierarchy. The tree is then displayed along with a live copy of your application.

Source: https://github.com/team-gryff/react-monocle

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for this now, I found this extention for VSCode. It's pretty nice. Just make sure to use the `Command center` to run `generate tree` command. It's not perfect, but it's best I could find.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HabeebArul.react-component-tree

Answer (score 2):

Use **Sapling**

Its a VSCODE extension.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=team-sapling.sapling

Comment: Devaka, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try React Developer Tools. It is a Chrome DevTools extension for React. It allows you to inspect the React component hierarchies in the Chrome Developer Tools. You can also inspect their state and other properties.

Comment: The OP is asking for tool that would create a component tree diagram. It should allow visualising the component tree as a whole.